# value from EricHynds Multiselect filter input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I am using EricHynds Multiselect filters plugin. It filters the values present in the dropdown when we enter some text in input field. But I want to send ajax request when user enters some text in input I can handle Ajax data easily but I am unable to fetch input field value.

Till now I am writing following code:

```
$(".container_filter").multiselect({}).multiselectfilter({
     filter: function(event, matches){
        console.log(event.currentTarget);
    }
});
```

But from it I am unable to get value of input field. 
My `console.log(event.currentTarget)` returns `<input type="search" placeholder="Enter keywords">`.

When I use `console.log(event.currentTarget.val())` then it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me

`console.log(event.currentTarget.value)`

will work fine.

As javascript is working in EricHynds plugin.

Comment: Worked fine. Thnks. :)

Comment: @عثمانغني It works fine when we type anything in that input box But when it is empty the function does not fire anything. So, is there any way to solve this ?